(aggregate) Intersection between values in an array of maps node js mongoose
What i'm trying to do is to find all values of key1 common in doc1 and doc2.
I have a collection called Signups with two documents doc1 & doc2
Signups : {
     _id : String,
     links : [
     {
     id:String,
     key1:String,
     }
     ]
     }

Doc1 : {
     _id:1,
     links :[{
     id:"22222",
     key1 :"oth"
     },
     {
     id:"33333",
     key1:"Sol"}]
     }
doc2 : {
     _id:2,
     links :[{
     id:"33333",
     key1:"Sol"
     },
     {
     id:"29921",
     key1:"BEM"}]
     }

I tried to use aggregate but i'm pretty sure there is an issue with the code below
 const result = await Signups.aggregate([
      // Étape 1 : Filtrer les deux documents par ID
      { $match: { _id: { $in: [1, 2] } } },
  
      // Étape 2 : Projeter uniquement les clés `key` des items
      {
        $project: {
          keys: {
            $map: {
              input: `$links`, // Your array of maps
              as: "item", // Alias for each item in the array
              in: `$$item.key1 ` // Accessing the Fe field inside each object
            }
          }
        }
      },
  
      // Étape 3 : Grouper tous les documents en un seul tableau
      {
        $group: {
          _id: null,
          allKeys: { $push: "$keys" } // Tableau de tableaux de clés
        }
      },
  
      // Étape 4 : Calculer l'intersection des clés entre les deux documents
      {
        $project: {
          commonKeys: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$allKeys",
              initialValue: [],
              in: { $setIntersection: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]);

as a result [ { _id: null, commonKeys: [] } ]
The commonKeys was empty even though it isn't
If someone has better thoughts please share them with us

"What i'm trying to do is" - Show what you have tried so far and what error you are facing. StackOverflow is not a code writing service. See How to ask a good question. And then read up on $setIntersection
